# configurable Parent Product set "Stock Availability" set auto magento-1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cataloginventory

I would like to do if any Child product has status "**in-stock**" parent status auto update "**in-stock**". else parent configurable product status update "**out-stock**". anyone can help me how can I do it with programming ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can using event observing like follows:

**NS_ProChange** is the module name.

Specify in `app/code/local/NS/ProChange/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NS_ProChange>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </NS_ProChange>
    </modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <productchange>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>NS_ProChange_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>detectProductChanges</method>
                </productchange>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Now in `app/code/local/NS/ProChange/Model/Observer.php`

```
class NS_ProChange_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function detectProductChanges($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        if( $product->getTypeId() != 'simple' ) {
            return false;
        }
        $parentId = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getParentIdsByChild( $product->getId() );

        if( $parentId[0] != '' ) {
            $inStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getIsInStock();          
            $configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $parentId[0] );
            if( $configProduct->getTypeId() == 'configurable' ) {
                $configProduct->setData('in_stock',$inStock);
                $configProduct->save();
            }           
        }   
    }
```

Create module activation file - `app/etc/modules/NS_ProChange.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NS_ProChange>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </NS_ProChange>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: i am new in magento plz can You guide in detail ?

Comment: i created those file NS/ProChange/etc/config.xml , NS/ProChange/Model/Observer.php
and i upload on my site root folder but its not working fine

Comment: Follow this tutorial - http://magenticians.com/create-magento-custom-module/

Comment: @Grace now check edited answer

Comment: again thanks for response bro i did same that above You guide me but still not solve my issue  on ***Stock Availability***

Comment: hi @same bro our module is not working why i don't know but i found a module that working  for product qty https://github.com/enru/magento-stock-status

Comment: @Grace ok enjoy